# How do I save and use Synergy Configuration file?

Tags: windows-7, synergy

When I try to save and use my configuration, I get this error message when Synergy starts.

```
NOTE: config file: C:/Program Files/Synergy/synergy.sgc
NOTE: log level: NOTE
synergys.exe: unrecognized option 'Files/Synergy/synergy.sgc'
Try 'synergys.exe --help' for more information.
```

It seems to only work if `Configure Interactively` is selected.

Using Synergy 64-bit, version 1.4.12 on Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

**[EDIT]** There is an issue when using spaces on the config file path.

> Had to install to c:\Synergy and then save my config file without
>   spaces in the name to work around this. Using version 1.4.10.

There seems to be another problem when using numbers on screen names.

I was having some trouble like this so I switched to the last stable version, 1.3.8 (http://synergy-foss.org/download/?file=synergy-1.3.8-Windows-x64.exe). Some features are missing but everything is working fine now.

Comment: The links are broken.